# Passing PHP variable from an input field to a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, database, hash, passwords

this is supposed to be a basic question but I'm learning. I'm making a log in system, user enters a username and a password. How do I send the password into my function hash via javascript. Cause I need to compare it afterwards with the one in my DB. If the password hashed = database password  then it is OK.

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="style.css" />

<!-- ... -->

<div align="center"> 
     <form action="connection.php" method="post">    
          <p>Fill your crendentials</p>
          <label for="usrUserName">Your login</label> 
          <input id="usrUserName" name="usrUserName" /><br />    
          <tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name="usrPassword" maxlength="25" id="usrPassword"/>    
          <form action="insert.php" method="post" onsumbit="return create_hash()">
     </form>
</div>
```

That's what I have at the moment. I can show you the function hash but people say it's not a good idea.

**EDIT My complete code**

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
define("PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM", "sha1");
define("PBKDF2_ITERATIONS", 1000);
define("PBKDF2_SALT_BYTES", 24);
define("PBKDF2_HASH_BYTES", 24);

define("HASH_SECTIONS", 4);
define("HASH_ALGORITHM_INDEX", 0);
define("HASH_ITERATION_INDEX", 1);
define("HASH_SALT_INDEX", 2);
define("HASH_PBKDF2_INDEX", 3);

function create_hash($usrPassword)
{


var usrPassword =document.getElementById("usrPassword").value;

   // format: algorithm:iterations:salt:hash
   $salt = base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(PBKDF2_SALT_BYTES, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
   return PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM . ":" . PBKDF2_ITERATIONS . ":" .  $salt . ":" .
       base64_encode(pbkdf2(
           PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM,
           $usrPassword,
           base64_decode($salt),
           PBKDF2_ITERATIONS,
           PBKDF2_HASH_BYTES,
           true

       )); 
       alert("usrPassword");
}

function validate_password($usrPassword, $good_hash)
{
   $params = explode(":", $good_hash);
   if(count($params) < HASH_SECTIONS)
      return false;
   $pbkdf2 = base64_decode($params[HASH_PBKDF2_INDEX]);
   return slow_equals(
       $pbkdf2,
       pbkdf2(
           $params[HASH_ALGORITHM_INDEX],
           $usrPassword,
           base64_decode($params[HASH_SALT_INDEX]),
           (int)$params[HASH_ITERATION_INDEX],
           strlen($pbkdf2),
           true
       )
   );
}
   </script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr">

    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="style.css" />



<div align = "center"> 
<form action = 'connection.php' method="post"  >

<p> Entrer vos informations  </p>

 <label for="usrUserName">Votre code d'usager </label> <input
id="usrUserName" name="usrUserName" /><br />

<label for="usrPassword">Votre mot de passe </label> <input
id="usrPassword" name="usrPassword" type="usrPassword" /><br />


<input type="submit" value="submit"   onsubmit=="return create_hash()">
</form>
```

Comment: get the value in input field -> hash it -> replace the result in the input -> invoke .submit()

Comment: You do not check hash in javascript, you need to do that at server side (php). If however you just want to hash it before sending to server for check (which doesn't make any sense) you should use ajax to submit your form.

Comment: Check on the server, best in DB. And don't forget to add some salt.

Comment: I have salt in my javascript and I don't want saver it in my database I just need to compare if my password = password hashed. And if you have exemple that will be nice guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the value as string:

```
<input type="button" name="myValue" value="Remove" onclick="del('<?echo $myArray[0]?>');"/>
```

you can also Use json_encode() to convert the value into value JavaScript:

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS YOUR HTML CODE:-

```
<form action = 'connection.php' method="post"  >

<p> Entrer vos informations  </p>

 <label for="usrUserName">Votre code d'usager </label> 
<input id="usrUserName" name="usrUserName" /><br />

   <tr><td>Password</td><td>
<input type="password" name="usrPassword" maxlength="25" id="usrPassword"/>
</td>

<form  action="insert.php" method="post" onsumbit="return create_hash()">
</form>
```

WHEN YOU CALL FUNCTION

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function create_hash(){

var pass =document.getElementById("usrPassword").value;

alert(pass);//here is your password
return false//for stop function
}

</script>
```

Comment: I edit my code I show my function don't care for security I'm learning.